# How to add ResearchGate preprints manually to google scholar?

Tags: publications, google-scholar, preprint

Is there any way of adding my ResearchGate preprints manually on Google Scholar? If no, will Google Scholar automatically add it to my scholar profile? Can other authors cite my ResearchGate preprints?

For the manual addition of my paper, I have performed the following steps.

For the manual addition of my paper at first I tried with **Add articles** option but I did not find it on scholar. Then I tried with **Add articles manually** but I did not find any preprint option there.

[image],

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google Scholar may well index your preprint on ResearchGate automatically after a few days, although it's rarely possible to be sure what Google Scholar will do, since it appears to run largely unattended.

You can manually add articles to your Google Scholar profile by going to your profile page and clicking on the plus icon just above the list of your publications:

[image]

Other people can cite anything you post to ResearchGate, although the citation format will depend on the citation standard (Harvard, APA, MLA etc) that they are using. [ResearchGate says it issues DOIs for preprints](https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/Preprints), which make it easier to cite them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special preprint option. You are supposed to use "Add articles manually" for your preprints and fill-in the fields accordingly.